# How can I use stdout.write in python 2.7 to display multiple lines at the same time?

Tags: python, python-2.7, stdout

I have a question regarding the python programming, let's say i have a loop, so within the loop, i want to stdout.write 3 variables in different lines.
For example:

```
while (True):
    a += 0
    b += 5
    c += 10
    sys.stdout.write("\routput1 = %d" % a)
    sys.stdout.write("\routput2 = %d" % b)
    sys.stdout.write("\routput3 = %d" % c)
```

So in the terminal should be like:

```
output1 = .........
output2 = .........
output3 = .........
```

Each output just remain in their lines and keep refreshing. Thank you!

Comment: for your current code what o/p you are getting ?

Comment: what OS are you on ?

Comment: "\r" means "moving the cursor to the beginning of the line", it's not related to python, it's for console and escape code.

Comment: @VikasDamodar aha my code is just an example, so i wanna ask how can i do sth using stdout.write do the result in differnet lines(i know the one above wont work :( )

Comment: @khelwood ok i will have a look

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo win10

Comment: @liliscent i use that because i want to keep "output =" still and only let the numbers change and refresh

Comment: @sunboy612 Not familiar with windows, but on Unix your approach is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple line printing, each console window on Windows is a number of lines, with number of columns... usually 25 lines and 80 columns as an old standard.

You can move a cursor to an (y, x) position, and print a string on screen.

y = line
x = column

Example code:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import c_long, c_wchar_p, c_ulong, c_void_p

handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(c_long(-11))

def move_console_cursor(y, x):
    value = (x + (y << 16))
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCursorPosition(handle, c_ulong(value)) 

def print_string_at_cursor(string):
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.WriteConsoleW (handle, c_wchar_p(string), c_ulong(len(string)), c_void_p(), None)
```

You then can print multiple lines over eachother by moving the cursor to the appropriate position and then print a string with the functions given.

A 3 line example: Easy would be to do a `os.system('CLS')` to clear the screen, and then you can move cursor to `1,1` `2,1` `3,1` and repeat until you have done all your processing. At the end, don't forget to move your cursor to `4,1`. You can of course pick any location of your console window.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but like I am using for example git bash or similar terminal, not windows command window, so is there a way to solve this for linux like console?

Comment: @sunboy612 you did not specify, and when asked you replied Win10. The answers you are looking for are already mentioned in the comments section.

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For single line on Windows you can do a `sys.stdout.write()` and then write cursor movements `'\b'` to move the cursor back to the beginning of the line.

Example of a copy file function with % progress indicator on the same line, using this method:

```
import os
import sys

def copy_progress(source_file, dest):
    source_size = os.stat(source_file).st_size
    copied = 0
    source = open(source_file, 'rb')
    target = open(dest, 'wb')
    print ('Copy Source: ' + source_file)
    print ('Copy Target: ' + dest)
    print ('Progress:')
    while True:
        chunk = source.read(512)
        if not chunk:
            break
        target.write(chunk)
        copied += len(chunk)
        progress = round(copied * 100 / source_size)
        my_progress = str(progress).ljust(5)
        sys.stdout.write (my_progress + '%\b\b\b\b\b\b')
        sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.flush()
    source.close()      
    target.close()
```

Comment: OK, but I want to have for example 3 progress indicator to display at the same time in 3 lines, how can i do it?

Comment: hence my second answer